# Inserting a row from dataframe to another dataframe where columns overlap

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['name','address','age','hobby'], index = ['num1','num2','num3'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['name','age'])
df2['name'] = ['David']
df2['age'] = [20]

# output should yield the same result as below
df1.iloc[0,:] = ['David', np.nan, 20, np.nan]
```

I want to insert the first row of df2 to the first row of df1 so that columns that don't overlap has NaN values. Can I do this without using for loop or assigning values individually? I am hoping to assign them in whole that requires the least amount of computation time. Thank you.

Comment: What does your expected output dataframe look like?

Comment: @ScottBoston updated thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can try something like this:

```
df2.rename({0:'num1'}).combine_first(df1)
```

Output:

```
      address   age  hobby   name
num1      NaN  20.0    NaN  David
num2      NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN
num3      NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Add reindex at the end.

```
df2.rename({0:'num1'}).combine_first(df1).reindex(df1.columns, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
       name  address   age  hobby
num1  David      NaN  20.0    NaN
num2    NaN      NaN   NaN    NaN
num3    NaN      NaN   NaN    NaN
```

Comment: This rearranges the columns. Is there a method to prevent this? Instead for writing another line?

Comment: @JHY Use reindex(df1.columns) at the end.  See update.

Comment: This helps a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also define it using `iloc`:

```
df1.iloc[0,[0,2]] = df2.values
```

Output:

```
       name address  age hobby
num1  David     NaN   20   NaN
num2    NaN     NaN  NaN   NaN
num3    NaN     NaN  NaN   NaN
```

Comment: In this case I would have to specify the columns manually which can be a problem if I am doing this in loops

Comment: If you are going for multiple columns, you can specify the range